# Get a Collection/Folder by name in google DOCS API

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to get a collection/Folder by it name but am getting an error, this what i got:

```
DocsService client = new DocsService("test testnet v1");
     //Get the ur to access google docs folders
     URL feedUrl=new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3Aroot?oauth_token="+token);

     DocumentQuery query = new DocumentQuery(feedUrl);
     query.setTitleQuery(name);
     query.setTitleExact(true);
     DocumentListFeed feed=null;

    try {
        feed = client.getFeed(query, DocumentListFeed.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Get the entry founded

     for (DocumentListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
            resourceId = entry.getDocId();
    }
```

Hope some one can help me, Thx.

Answer (score 3):

using url https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/folder will list the folders (or you can do a search query by name). From that list, you can find your folder by name and then do a query by resource id using 
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/[resource id]/contents

I don't think there is an easier way.